# Is there a way to draw confusion matrix with known True Positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

Today I have finished processing some data and came to conclusion that I have the following final tables containing:

|  | Counts. |
| --- | --- |
| True Positive | 23070 |
| True Negative | 4503 |
| False Positive | 28 |
| False Negative | 34 |

I am trying to construct a confusion matrix here, scikit-learn.confusion_matrix style, but I cant figure out how. Can I use Matplotlib for this instead?
Do you guys ever come to his type of quest?
I believe we can draw it somehow.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With `scikit-learn.confusion_matrix` You can get the confusion matrix by
`cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)`

And the confusion matrix is already in the form
`TP|FN`
`FP|TN`

You can use seaborn's heatmap to plot the data:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='Blues')
```

If you already have the data then try storing it in a list of list then plot the data using seaborn:

```py
cm_data = [[23070, 34], [4503, 28]]
sns.heatmap(cm_data, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='d')
```

[image]